# Parallel processing for multiple nested for loops

Tags: r, foreach

I am trying to run simulation scenarios which in turn should provide me with the best scenario for a given date, back tested a couple of months. The input for a specific scenario has 4 input variables with each of the variables being able to be in 5 states (625 permutations).  The flow of the model is as follows:

1. Simulate 625 scenarios to get each of their profit
2. Rank each of the scenarios according to their profit
3. Repeat the process through a 1-day expanding window for the last 2 months starting on the 1st Dec 2015 - creating a time series of ranks for each of the 625 scenarios

The unfortunate result for this is 5 nested for loops which can take extremely long to run. I had a look at the `foreach` package, but I am concerned around how the combining of the outputs will work in my scenario.

The current code that I am using works as follows, first I create the possible states of each of the inputs along with the window

```
a<-seq(as.Date("2015-12-01", "%Y-%m-%d"),as.Date(Sys.Date()-1, "%Y-%m-%d"),by="day")
#input variables
b<-seq(1,5,1)
c<-seq(1,5,1)
d<-seq(1,5,1)
e<-seq(1,5,1)

set.seed(3142)

tot_results<-NULL
```

Next the nested for loops proceed to run through the simulations for me.

```
for(i in 1:length(a))
{
cat(paste0("\n","Current estimation date: ", a[i]),";itteration:",i," \n")
#subset data for backtesting
dataset_calc<-dataset[which(dataset$Date<=a[i]),]
p=1
results<-data.frame(rep(NA,625))
    for(j in 1:length(b))
    {
        for(k in 1:length(c))
        {
            for(l in 1:length(d))
            {
                for(m in 1:length(e))
                {
                if(i==1)
                {
                    #create a unique ID to merge onto later
                    unique_ID<-paste0(replicate(1, paste(sample(LETTERS, 5, replace=TRUE), collapse="")),round(runif(n=1,min=1,max=1000000)))
                }
                #Run profit calculation
                post_sim_results<-profit_calc(dataset_calc, param1=e[m],param2=d[l],param3=c[k],param4=b[j])
                #Exctract the final profit amount
                profit<-round(post_sim_results[nrow(post_sim_results),],2)

                results[p,]<-data.frame(unique_ID,profit)
                p=p+1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #extract the ranks for all scenarios
    rank<-rank(results$profit)

    #bind the ranks for the expanding window
    if(i==1)
        {
            tot_results<-data.frame(ID=results[,1],rank)
        }else{
            tot_results<-cbind(tot_results,rank)
        }
    suppressMessages(gc())
}
```

My biggest concern is the binding of the results given that the outer loop's actions are dependent on the output of the inner loops.

Any advice on how proceed would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: From your code, it seems as though you can just vectorize the whole thing? With `expand.grid(a,b,c,d,e)` as your input.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful comment. My background is unfortunately not programming based, so although I understand the concept of 'vectorizing' the problem, I have not implemented these structures before. Do you know of a good source perhaps where I could go look at some examples? Or perhaps if you could be so kind as to provide a sample of say a nested loop with 3 `for` functions which I could just build up from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think that you can vectorize most of this, which should give a big reduction in run time.

Currently, you use `for`-loops (5, to be exact) to create every combination of values, and then run the values one by one through `profit_calc` (a function that is not specified). Ideally, you'd just take all possible combinations in one go and push them through `profit_calc` in one single operation.

**-- Rationale --**

```
a <- 1:10
b <- 1:10
d <- rep(NA,10)
for (i in seq(a)) d[i] <- a[i] * b[i]
d 

# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

Since `*` also works on vectors, we can rewrite this to:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- 1:10
d <- a*b
d

# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

While it may save us only one line of code, it actually reduces the problem from 10 steps to 1 step.

**-- Application --**

So how does that apply to your code? Well, given that we can vectorize `profit_calc`, you can basically generate a data frame where each row is every possible combination of your parameters. We can do this with `expand.grid`:

```
foo <- expand.grid(b,c,d,e)
head(foo)

#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
# 1    1    1    1    1
# 2    2    1    1    1
# 3    3    1    1    1
# 4    4    1    1    1
# 5    5    1    1    1
# 6    1    2    1    1
```

Lets say we have a formula... `(a - b) / (c + d)`... Then it would work like:

```
bar <- (foo[,1] - foo[,2]) * (foo[,3] + foo[,4])
head(bar)

# [1]  0  2  4  6  8 -2
```

So basically, try to find a way to replace `for`-loops with vectorized options. If you cannot vectorize something, try looking into `apply` instead, as that can also save you some time in most cases. If your code is running too slow, you'd ideally first see if you can write a more efficient script. Also, you may be interested in the `microbenchmark` library, or `?system.time`.

Comment: thanks for this concise and intuitive explanation! Really appreciate it